# Is the order of columns important in GROUP BY clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

As you know, the `GROUP BY` clause is used in conjunction with the aggregate functions to group the result-set by one or more columns.

Something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(col1), col2, col3
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY col2, col3
WHERE 1
```

---

**My question:** `GROUP BY col2, col3` and `GROUP BY col3, col2` are the same? Based on the tests I have to say yes, the result will be identical for both orders. But I need to be sure about it .. Are they identical?

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP BY` comes after `WHERE`. In terms of results returned, order of group by columns is is irrelevant; however, MySQL (currently*) also orders by the group by columns.

*"currently" as in documentation over the last few years indicates that behavior may not be in future versions.